# Control if connected on my website with iphone or ipad Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can I know using javascript if the user is connected to my webpage with an Iphone or with an Ipad. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean whether the browser is Safari for iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an example of the 2 useragent strings returned when using Safari :

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us)
>   AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b
>   Safari/531.21.10
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1C25 Safari/419.3

so you can use

`navigator.userAgent.match(/iphone/i)` for iPhone

or

`navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad/i)` for iPad

Comment: Thanks I used navigator.userAgent.search('iPad') > 0 and same for iPhone